# Parse string using shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to get `NetworkActivity_5851_*_09-04-2016.done` string from `NetworkActivity_5851_2326316_09-04-2016.log.gz` and here the code I wrote

```
local file="$1"
local extension="${file##*.}"
if [ $extension = 'done' ]; then
   local files=`basename $file`
   files="${files#*_}"
   files="${files#*_}"
   files="${files%_*}"
   local q=_"$files"_
   local mask="${file/done/log.gz}"
   mask="${mask/${q}/_*_}"
   r=`ls "${mask}" | wc -l`
```

and it works correct, but when I run it with python script it fails. I mean `r` variable has wrong value.
Here is code in Python

```
    shell = Shell(RUN_SCRIPT_2, LOGFILE)
```

where Shell is

```
class Shell():
    """
    Base class for the shell script object which
    is under testing.
    """

    def __init__(self, path_to_script, path_to_log=None):
        """
        executes shell script and store results
        of STDOUT and STDERR into appropriate attributes
        """
        self.path_to_log = path_to_log
        # clear log file before run
        if self.path_to_log:
            open(self.path_to_log, 'w').close()

        shell = subprocess.Popen([path_to_script],
                                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                 shell=True)
        # the line below makes sure shell command execution finished
        self.stdout, self.stderr = shell.communicate()
        self.log_data = self.get_log_data()
```

and file path_to_script is

```
echo 'Start' 
file="${SOURCE_DIR}/NetworkActivity_5851_3_09-04-2016.done"
    extension="${file##*.}"
    if [ $extension = 'done' ]; then
       files=`basename $file`
       files="${files#*_}"
       files="${files#*_}"
       files="${files%_*}"
       q=_"$files"_
       mask="${file/done/log.gz}"
       mask="${mask/${q}/_*_}"
       r=`ls "${mask}" | wc -l`
       echo $r
       if [ $r = $files ]; then
          rez=0
       else rez=1
       fi    
fi
if [[ $rez -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo "Failure"
else echo "Success"
fi
echo 'Finish'
```

So when I run path_to_script from terminal `r` variable sets number of files when I run it using Python it sets 0.

Comment: @Inian it should be number of file that has name as template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using `bash` string-manipulation techniques alone.

```
$ inputString="NetworkActivity_5851_2326316_09-04-2016.log.gz"
$ substring="${inputString%%.*}"                                      # Removing the part after the first '.'
$ [[ $substring =~ .*_([[:digit:]]+)_.* ]] && NUM=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}  # Extracting the number you want to replace 
$ finalString="${substring/$NUM/*}.done"                              # Forming the final string with the extension

$ printf "%s\n" "$finalString"
NetworkActivity_5851_*_09-04-2016.done
```

You can put together this logic in a shell script and run the same for multiple files you have. The above commands though can be run directly on the console.

Comment: There is one more problem if `_2326316_` will be `_8_` for example. `${substring/$NUM/*}.done` replaces first occurrence of 8. I tried `${substring/_$NUM_/_*_}.done` but it replaces first occurrence of _

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm based on your first paragraph. Hope I got the problem! This is my solution with Perl and regular expression with a simple command line.

```
~$ gunzip NetworkActivity_5851_2326316_09-04-2016.log.gz && perl  -e 'while(<>){print $_ if $_ =~ /NetworkActivity_\d+_.*_\d{2}\-\d{2}-\d{4}\.done/}' NetworkActivity_5851_2326316_09-04-2016.log
```

Hope it helps!